# Mounting /etc/default directory problem with SOLR image

Tags: kubernetes

I'm deploying a basic "solr:8.9.0" image to local Kubernetes env.

If I'm trying to mount pod's "/var/solr" directory, it works well.
I can see the files inside /var/solr in the mounted directory.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: solr:8.6.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: solr
    ports:
        - name: solrport
          containerPort: 8983
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/solr/
      name: solr-volume
  volumes:
  - name: solr-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: solr-pvc
```

But somehow I can't mount "/etc/default/" directory. That doesn't work.
I knew there are files inside that directory but they are disappearing.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is because of how volumeMounts work.
A standard volumeMount mounts the volume in the suplied directory overwriting everything that is inside that directory.

You want to specify a subpath for the data you actually want to mount. By doing this the original contents of the directory won't get overridden.

see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) for more information regarding the usage of subpaths.